# What is the purpose of /var/lib/sss/ in centos 8?

Tags: centos, centos8

In a centos 8 desktop linux, after I login the system from the UI. I ran the command below from the terminal:

```
[joe@joe mc]$  ls -al /proc/self/fd 
total 0
dr-x------. 2 joe joe  0 May 20 13:59 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 9 joe joe  0 May 20 13:59 ..
lrwx------. 1 joe joe 64 May 20 13:59 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 joe joe 64 May 20 13:59 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------. 1 joe joe 64 May 20 13:59 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lr-x------. 1 joe joe 64 May 20 13:59 3 -> /var/lib/sss/mc/passwd
lr-x------. 1 joe joe 64 May 20 13:59 4 -> /var/lib/sss/mc/group
lr-x------. 1 joe joe 64 May 20 13:59 5 -> /proc/3419/fd
```

I notice `/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd` and `/var/lib/sss/mc/group`. I tried to read `/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd` and `/var/lib/sss/mc/group`. But it only shows some non printable chars.

I am not familiar with `/var/lib/sss`. What is the purpose of this directory and its subdirectories such as `/var/lib/sss/mc`?

Comment: Google, ' purpose of /var/lib/sss ' : One of the first hits says → "/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd is the cache file of for user information with SSSD/LDAP users."